# String have special characters in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want following string to store in variable but It's giving error in SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @string nvarchar(max)

set @string=''˗ˏˋmichaelˎˊ˗''
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: "but It's giving error". What error?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '˗'.

Comment: I just want it as string.

Comment: There are no special characters in Unicode. I suspect you are concatenating strings to construct a sql query and found out that *any* punctuation can result in an invalid query. Simply *don't* use concatenation, use parameterized queries.

Comment: You don't need to double quote it: `SET @string = '˗ˏˋmichaelˎˊ˗';`

Comment: can you please type in the string you want is it '˗ˏˋmichaelˎˊ˗'

Comment: @WaleedAli if that's your actual code, the error is very obvious. You have an empty string followed by a bunch of characters. Did you intent to escape the single quote character perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ' is a string delimiter in t-sql. If you want to include that character in your string you need to double them. You also need to specify that your string literal is nvarchar by preceding the string with N.

```
DECLARE @string nvarchar(max)

set @string= N'''˗ˏˋmichaelˎˊ˗'''

select @string
```